# Is there a way to get data from Oracle to a form stored on SharePoint 2007?

Tags: oracle, sharepoint-2007

I need the document or form to be automatically updated when the data in the Oracle database is updated.  If not possible, could anyone give me guidance to a solution similar to this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle supports [triggers in Java](http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/java/jsp/oracle9ijsp.html), so you could execute some code when data is changed in the DB. Sharepoint 2007 does support WebServices, so you could create a client which calls the web service to update the form.

But that sounds more simple than it is. The documentation for the web services in Sharepoint ... uh ... could be better. Many installations of Sharepoint insist on domain logins, so you would need to figure out a way to run Oracle with a Windows Domain logon.

In the end, it's probably more simple to create an email when the data changes in Oracle and have someone manually update the form.

That said, you paid a lot of money to Microsoft for Sharepoint, so they are obliged to tell you which API to use and they can probably even provide an example in, say C#. If all else fails, you can run a little server in C# which updates the form and which listens to data packets sent by a Java trigger in Oracle.

[EDIT] [Here is a blog post][2](http://blog.pdark.de/2008/11/26/navigating-sharepoint-folders-with-axis2/) to get you started with Java, Apache Axis and Sharepoint. Post a comment if you have any updates. <s>Lu</s>Unfortunately, I'm no longer working at a company which uses Sharepoint.

Comment: My boss asked me if it was possible to do this, we discussed it and we will try setting up an ODBC connection with an Excel Spreadsheet and post that to SharePoint.  He didn't want to go through something that complicated.  Thanks for the quick reply.